# Integral $\int(\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt{x}})$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

evaluate the indefinite integral please
$$\int\left(\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt{x}}\right)$$
No ideas how to evaluate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if we take the substitution $u=x^{1/6}
 $ we get $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt{x}}=6\int\frac{u^{3}}{u+1}du
 $$ then, use the identity $$\frac{u^{3}}{u+1}=u^{2}-u-\frac{1}{u+1}+1.$$